# Как вывести в цикле на Python часть последовательно расположенных символов unicode?

Tags: python, циклы, unicode

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Python вывести в цикле символы unicode.
Нужно, чтобы значения элементов матрицы отображались в виде букв латинского алфавита и арабских цифр: a1, a2,...b1, b2...h1,h2...

```
<python>

     class matrix:

       def __init__(self,n,m):

        b=[0]*n
        for i in range(n):
            b[i]=[0]*m

        for i in range(0,m,1):

            for r in range(0,n,1):
                letter=61+i
                #b[i][r]=(str(i) + str(r)+"  ")
                #b[i][r]=str('\x61') + str(r)+" ")
                b[i][r]=str('\xletter') + str(r)+" ")

        for row in b:
            for elem in row:
                print (elem, end=' ')
            print()

    mat=matrix(10,10)

</python>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from string import lowercase
for i in xrange(26):
    print lowercase[i]
```

Comment: Да! Как вариант! Спасибо большое!

А есть возможность преобразовать числовую переменную в шестнадцатиричном виде в индекс unicode?

Comment: Думаю, что можно. Что вы подразумеваете под "индекс unicode"?

Comment: Под индексом unicode подразумеваю - числовой код символа

u'\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442'

Существует ли возможность их преобразовывать из шестнадцатиричного числового типа в символьный и наоборот?

Например, если необходимо обратится к срезу элементов массива из символов unicode с интервалом больше 1

Comment: Не совсем понял, о чем вы, но если вам нужно преобразовать шестнадцатеричное число в символ unicode:

Возьмем, например, букву я. В unicode она выглядит так u'\u044F', то есть ее номер 44f

    >>> print unichr(int('44f', 16))
    я

Если нужно наоборот, воспользуйтесь функцией ord, она вернет десятичное представление номера символа, но мы его превратим в шестнадцатеричное:

    >>> print hex(ord(u'я'))
    0x44f

Comment: Да, с функциями преобразования все получилось 

Вы правильно меня поняли! Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы напечатать все Юникод символы по 40 символов в строке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from itertools import zip_longest

all_chars = map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1))
for chars in zip_longest(*[all_chars]*40, fillvalue=''):
    print(''.join(chars))
```

Чтобы напечатать все ascii пары "буква + цифра":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

print(' '.join(map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, digits))))
```

#### Результат

```
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 b0 b1 ...
y8 y9 z0 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z7 z8 z9
```